# Getting error when using function tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf

i created following code but i get error "TCPDF ERROR: Error in 1D barcode string", what is wrong with this code?

```
$pdf->write1DBarcode(cooode($balance), 'C128C', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');
```

code works fine when i add it in example here

```
$pdf->Cell(35,0,cooode($balance),0,0,'L',0); # eräpäivä
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason why you are getting this error is that the value being passed as the first parameter, ie. the result of `cooode($balance)` is not in a valid format according to the rules for the C128C encoding.